# how to retrieve response.error and response.success messages in c# (Unity3D)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I had the exactly same problem with this thread
https://www.parse.com/questions/how-to-retrieve-responseerror-and-responsesuccess-messages-in-c-unity3d

which is archived without any comment or question.

On the cloud code

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("GameScore", function(request, response) {
        response.error("MY_ERROR_CODE");});
```

In Unity C# code:

```
ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<string>("Function", paramsDict)
            .ContinueWith(t => {

                if(t.IsFaulted){
                    foreach(Exception e in t.Exception.InnerExceptions){
                        ParseException ex = (ParseException)e;
                        Debug.Log (ex.Message); 
                    }
                }
                Debug.Log ("HERE1");    
                string result = t.Result
                Debug.Log ("HERE2");    
});
```

The output is always "400 Bad Request", or something not my own error code "MY_RRROR_CODE".
I want to make my app know the different errors exactly to have corresponding result.

Questions:

1. How can I get "MY_ERROR_CODE" in Unity?
2. Why "HERE1" is printed in the console but not "HERE2"? Every code after "string result = t.Result" is not called. Am I missing some important features of the ContinueWith function?

Answer (score 0):

In your Cloud Code you aren't creating a Cloud Function called `Function`, you are only creating a `beforeSave()` handler.

In your Unity C# code your `string result = t.Result` doesn't have a `;` at the end, otherwise it should work.

Answer (score 0):

According to Christine Abernathy here: https://www.parse.com/questions/unity-sdk-handling-errors ... it's not possible to get more information about errors from Parse in Unity because of Unity's limited HTTP stack.

Comment: Is this still the case? Its really really annoying!